# Get Instagram User feed

Tags: python, request, xmlhttprequest, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to get the data correlated with a user's feed tab on Instagram. Every time I google "get user feed" or anything similar, I am presented with how to get the recent photos that a user has posted.

However, I am trying to get the feed tab, or basically the trending posts of other people that I follow. I tried using Lev Pasha's Instagram API module, but the only related function that I could find was `getPopularFeed()`, which got posts from the explore page.

I know how to connect to the Instagram API and have done it using the code below, but have not managed to collect the feed tab.

```
from InstagramAPI import InstagramAPI

InstagramAPI = InstagramAPI("myusername", "mypassword")
InstagramAPI.login()
```

---

Update (6/2/2021):

I've decided to add a bit of info here regarding the Instagram API. I'd like to say that this answer is slightly "deprecated" in a sense, as the GitHub repo for this project has been taken down, and therefore it will become harder to develop updates and bug fixes for the module. As a result, I'd actually recommend that you *don't* use this module, as it will get you banned very quickly from the Instagram platform (the last update was in 2018, and therefore any User-Agent fixes and bot-detection workarounds will not be added).

I'd also like to say that as of now, there seem to be no good modules for the task of Instagram automation. As I've just said, the InstagramAPI module written in my post is long gone, and all the other API projects on Github are also archived / have no more moderation or updates.

TLDR: Maintaining an API which is being updated constantly by a huge corporation is not easy, and therefore you will get banned / blocked easily. I'd recommend using [Lev Pasha's](https://pypi.org/project/InstagramAPI/) or [ping's](https://github.com/ping/instagram_private_api) Instagram APIs, although they are both deprecated and might get you blocked quickly. The [module in the answer below](https://github.com/uriyyo/instapi) is also pretty good, although I've noticed that it hasn't been updated in almost 2 years. Also, it's built as a wrapper on top of ping's API.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `instapi` module to solve your problem. [Link to repo](https://github.com/uriyyo/instapi)

Code example:

```py
from instapi import bind, User


bind('myusername', 'mypassword')

user = User.from_username('some username')

for feed in user.iter_feeds():
    # do something with feed
```

To install `instapi` using `pip`:

```sh
pip install git+https://github.com/uriyyo/instapi
```